# Xamp VM on MAC not letting me open my Laravel project via terminal

Tags: php, laravel, macos, terminal, xampp

Recently xampp has introduced Xamp-VM for MAC OS but its not letting me open my laravel project via terminal I need to run `php artisan` commands in my laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal in Xampp run the command again

Comment: which command? It would'nt let you go to htdocs directory because it now creates a virtual machine for every new project after latest update for mac